# Using multiple properties when adding an entity to a Symfony2 form

Tags: mysql, forms, entity-framework, symfony

I have something that's been puzzling me, so I thought I'd ask here.

I'm building a form in a Symfony2 project, and one of the fields is an entity, which will add the value to a join table. The entity in this case is called "Vehicle" and the table contains information about a vehicle in a fleet. However, there are two fields that make up the vehicle name, i.e. Make and Model. When I use this entity in my form, I can only seem to use ONE property (either Make or Model) and not concatenate them.

Here is the code that renders the Vehicle drop down entity in the form:

```
$builder->add('vehicle'  , 'entity',
        array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Vehicle',
            'label' => 'Vehicle',
            'empty_value' => '-- Please Select --',
            'property' => 'model',
            'multiple' => false
        ));
```

In this case, the drop down will only show the Model, and not the Make. Is it possible to make it so I can concatenate these in order to show both Make and Model in my form? For example:

```
$builder->add('vehicle'  , 'entity',
        array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Vehicle',
            'label' => 'Vehicle',
            'empty_value' => '-- Please Select --',
            'property' => 'make' + 'model',
            'multiple' => false
        ));
```

Or something like that so that the drop down will read "Ford Transit" instead of just "Transit"?

Any help appreciated.
Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a method  __toString() in your AppBundle:Vehicle class, which will return concatenated make and model. And omit a 'property' option at all.